# ckeditor uploading images

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor, image-upload

So I have my ckeditor working nicely together with the uploader of the fckeditor.
But only on localhost.
When uploaded to my server, the file manager uploads the Photo to the designated folder, but doesn't seem to get the url back for implementing it in the editor. I then always get the error of "image source url is missing".
Can anyone tell me what I am missing here ?
How come it works on localhost and doesn't on the server ?
I do think I changed all the appropriate paths.

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Too broad and too few details. You use some version of some uploader on some server and have some problem. Too much to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this error in CKEditor when you upload image file. This problem is due CKEDITOR open dialog in a frame so ; for solving this error check the "X-FRAME-OPTION" in you htaccess  and set the value to SAMEORIGIN instead of DENY. If it's not in your htaccess it's when you send http header in your app.

For PHP before send content just set header like this :

```
   header('X-FRAME-OPTION : SAMEORIGIN');
```

For more information about X-FRAME-OPTION check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

in my case (in .htaccess) it was obligatory to unset the header value first which was added by (I suppose) server:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I used this code. but it's not unsetting old x-frame-options. So giving error "it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'."